# MahApps MetroWindow Topmost property Binding issue

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I am using MahApps for my WPF application and when the metro window is used, the TopMost property is not able to bind. If i set it as a static value it works though.

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="SabreContractSearch.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        Topmost= "{Binding Pin}" Title="{Binding Title}" Height="350" Width="525" Name="FrmMainWindow" >
```

Pin is a boolean property here.

If i remove the metro window and use the normal window tag for WPF, it works. Anything additionally need to add for metro window to work?

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in ControlzEx v4.2.1. There is a Topmost hack which doesn't set the Topmost property of the Window using the SetCurrentValue.

WPF0041 Set mutable dependency properties using SetCurrentValue.

Setting the value of dependency properties using the CLR accessor calls SetValue(Property, value). This will kill one-way bindings on the property. This rule is probably most relevant in library code where accidentally setting a value can be a hard to track down bug.